# Is it possible to configure spring.cloud.config to use multiple bootstrap.yml files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-config, configmap

I am mounting multiple volumes into my pod, each being a configMap that contain different pieces of what would fully construct Spring Cloud **bootstrap.yaml** file. For example, one configMap may contain the config server URI, and the second configMap may contain overrideSystemProperties property. These configMaps are laid down in files with different names (or with the same name but in different paths) in the pod. My question is is it possible to configure Spring Cloud to use multiple **bootstrap.yaml** files? I know one can configure Spring to look for additional properties in different locations using spring.config.additional-location. Is it possible to do the same with Spring Cloud bootstrap?

Comment: The same rules apply to the bootstrap files. You can have different ones per environment.